# unwanted full_body_spacer with big height value getting added on html site

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website url is capsicumtech.in/vigilante, as you can see there is unwanted space getting added just above the footer and I cant figure out why,
I have tried using universal margin and padding also

html,body{padding:0;margin:0;}

but nothing helped.

Thanks

Comment: Solved it by myself by adding display:inline-block; to body

Answer (score 0):

the height of span element with class full_body_spacer is
 adding the extra space,remove the height from it it

Comment: I did not added that span element in html code its appearing automatically, also removing its height from css is not reliable solution.